# file:///user/home/file.xhtml displays properly but http://website.com/file.xhtml does not

Tags: xhtml

I converted a genealogical gedcom file to xhtml to post to my website. The file displays properly when loaded into Firefox or Chrome from my computer using file:///home/user/file.xhtml but when uploaded to my website and accessed as

```
http://website.com/file.xhtml
```

both browsers merely list the contents as a text file. Is there any simple way to get the file to work from the web? Here are the first few lines of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
        <html:html xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xml:lang="nl">
        <html:head>
        <html:meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <html:title></html:title>
        <html:style>
```

Comment: file:// is not available over IP. It is only available over another network type.

Comment: For this to work the way you expect, your file ***MUST*** be available to the web server within your website's web space. It cannot be anywhere else with one exception. You can create a symbolic link from your website to your file.

Comment: @closetnoc  I have clarified my question.

Comment: Ah Hah!! Much better!! BTW- John Hopkins APL? You were stomping on my terf when I was working. I shot for their pistol team years ago. Retired in PA now. Cheers!!

Comment: BTW- You should get an good answer soon enough! It is likely something simple such as a MIME or file association setting in Apache. You may need to restart it. Busy doing accounting... so I better pay attention.

Comment: "browsers merely list the contents as a text file" - As closetnoc suggests, this sounds like a mime-type issue. Your server may not know what mime-type to serve for a `.xhtml` file. Check the server response, you should be seeing `application/xhtml+xml` (as in the `meta` tag) if this is true XHTML. Also check to make sure this is valid XHTML.

Comment: @w3dk You're right, it's showing as Content-Type: text/plain. The site is hosted by earthlink.com, so I will contact them if the xhtml checks out as valid.

Answer (score 1):

> ... it's showing as Content-Type: text/plain.

Providing the file has validated successfully as XHTML/XML then (assuming you are on an Apache web server) you can try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the document root (or your server config, if you have access):

```
AddType application/xhtml+xml xhtml
```

<sup>(I assume all modern browsers understand XHTML these days?!)</sup>

Comment: XHTML, which is XML, is heavily used despite rumors of its demise.

Comment: I tried adding "AddType application/xhtml+xml xhtml" to .htaccess but that did not fix it. The XML checks as valid but not the xhtml which has many many errors according to an online xhtml checker. I'm using a plugin for a genealogical program which allegedly turns your genealogical data (gedcom format) into a xhtml file. I was posting it for the benefit of my relatives. I may just have them download the file and open it in their browsers offline since it displays properly that way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of problems with Gedcom file conversion and web hosting.

Have you checked your export file sources to see if codes match original source codes?

Export done with UT-8 coding? Tried HTML export opposed to XHTML?

Some software is proprietary and will only work on your machine and the proprietary server. You mentioned in the uploaded file errors exist. Also see if links are pointing to different folders on your machine and not actually being uploaded.

**You might want try a different convertor first.** Here is a link to GED2www, which is free for mac and pc.

http://lesandchris.com/gene-ged2www

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am currently searching for a different converter. The GED2www does not run on my system (linux) and the source code zip file appears to be corrupted or I would compile from scratch. However I am trying a couple of other programs and may try to run GED2www under wine.